# Managed Availability Thresholds for Exchange 2016

Tags: exchange, exchange-2013

We are constantly getting alerts in SCOM from the Exchange Managed Health/Availability services for disk space issues!

For example;

```
Database 'MBXDB' is low on log volume space. 'MBXDB' is low on log volume space [H:\]. Current=55 GB, Threshold=175.78 GB"
```

The documentation online for overriding these thresholds is sparse, or at least, for what the questions I'm asking.

We have separate drives for DBs and LOGs (as per normal), yet there seems to be no way to distinguish between these for the disk thresholds? Or none I've found.

It looks like a global, one value setting, that will impact all disks?

```
Add-GlobalMonitoringOverride -Item Monitor –Identity MailboxSpace\StorageLogicalDriveSpaceMonitor -PropertyName MonitoringThreshold -PropertyValue 30 -ApplyVersion 15.0.847.32
```

But what if 30GB is a huge chunk of that disk, or too smaller chunk, we have drives of all different sizes. Does it impact C: drive as well? Does this affect both LOG and EBD disks? Can we setup seperate global overrides for different volumes? What about mount points?

I cant seem to find answers to these questions, so any advice is appreciated.

This is the log:

```
    Database 'MBX' is low on log volume space. 'MBX' is low on log volume space [J:\]. Current=100.62 GB, Threshold=175.78 GB

'MBX' is low on EDB volume space [I:\]. Current=100 GB, Threshold=175.78 GB
```

It still continues to see the default 175.78GB Threshold, even after adding the global override above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to **Belinda Ma**'s post in the similar thread **[Database 'Servername' is low on log volume space. 'DBname' is low on log volume space](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/80fe073a-7005-443a-8adb-93b463c97a8e/database-servername-is-low-on-log-volume-space-dbname-is-low-on-log-volume-space?forum=exchangesvradmin)**, if we encounter the "**low on log volume space**", it is caused because that we have a hard coded limit of specific value(**Yours: 175.78GB**) for log drive space but there’s not the free space of it.

To fix the log space issue, you could try to modify or add the registry key(**DWORD**) **SpaceMonitorLowSpaceThresholdInMB** to **REG_DWORD c350(50000)** in the path **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\ExchangeServer\v15\Replay\Parameters** or **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\ExchangeServer\v15\ActiveMonitoring\Parameters**, then reboot your machine to check the result:
[image]